# Group by and format a list of authors

Tags: javascript, html, css, formatting

given the following javascript Object

```
[
  {"name":"Albert Trucmuche","role":"Textes","licence":"CC BY-NC-ND"},
  {"name":"Nina Machin","role":"Illustrations","licence":"Tous droits réservés"},
  {"name":"Roberta Bidulle","role":"Textes","licence":"CC BY-NC-ND"}
]
```

How can I get this?

```
"Albert Trucmuche et Roberta Bidulle <small>CC BY-NC-ND</small><br>Illustrations: Nina Machin"
```

So the general idea is to group authors first by medium (Textes, Illustrations, etc.) then by licence. Then format am HTML string that gracefully join the authors (using commas and "et" if it is the last author).

The licence does not need to appear if it is "Tous droits réservés".

I'm open to other HTML+CSS structure/styling if it makes things easier.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to formatting the data first

```
const members = [
  {"name":"Albert Trucmuche","role":"Textes","licence":"CC BY-NC-ND"},
  {"name":"Nina Machin","role":"Illustrations","licence":"Tous droits réservés"},
  {"name":"Roberta Bidulle","role":"Textes","licence":"CC BY-NC-ND"}
];
// Get all the roles from members
// Use Set to remove duplicate data and convert Set to Array again
// result = [ "Textes", "Illustrations" ]
const roles = Array.from(new Set(members.map(d => d.role)));

// Mapping roles and filter all licenses from members based on selected role
// result =
// [
//     { "role": "Textes", "licenses": [ "CC BY-NC-ND" ] },
//     { "role": "Illustrations", "licenses": [ "Tous droits réservés" ] }
// ]
const rolesWithLicenses = roles.map(role => {
    return {
        "role": role,
        "licenses": Array.from(new Set(members.filter(d => d.role === role ).map(d => d.licence)))
    };
});

// Mapping rolesWithLicenses and filter all members based on selected role and license
// result =
// [
//     {
//         "role":"Textes",
//         "licenses":
//         [
//             {
//                 "license":"CC BY-NC-ND",
//                 "members":["Albert Trucmuche","Roberta Bidulle"]
//             }
//         ]
//     },
//     {
//         "role":"Illustrations",
//         "licenses":
//         [
//             {
//                 "license":"Tous droits réservés",
//                 "members":["Nina Machin"]
//             }
//         ]
//     }
// ]
const res = rolesWithLicenses.map(role => {
    const licensesWithMembers = role.licenses.map(license => {
        return {
            "license": license,
            "members":  members.filter(member => member.licence === license && member.role === role.role).map(data => data.name)
        };
    });
    role['licenses'] = licensesWithMembers;
    return role;
});
```

Now you can free to render the data with your format using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)